# SOAPUI DateFormat error

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, soapui, date-format

I am new here, sorry if I make any mistake posting my question. I am using SOAPUI to test a web service. Inside the Soap message, I need to add an StartDate and EndDate but I am getting as a error (Input string was not in a correct format)
I been trying several DateFormat that I found over the internet by I still getting the same error.

Here you have the SOAPUI parameters.

Thanks

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <tem:Message>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:Value>?</tem:Value>
      </tem:Message>
      <tem:APIKeyHeader>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:Value>cbe40420</tem:Value>
      </tem:APIKeyHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetTasks>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:PIDs>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <tem:string>2857fd7c-a720</tem:string>
         </tem:PIDs>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:UserID>blue</tem:UserID>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:IDs>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <tem:string>?</tem:string>
         </tem:IDs>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:TaskStatus>true</tem:TaskStatus>
         <tem:StartDate>2008-10-26T21:32:52.12679</tem:StartDate>
         <tem:EndDate>2014-10-26T21:32:52.12679</tem:EndDate>
         <tem:ExtentionDays>true</tem:ExtentionDays>
         <tem:ShowNotReady>false</tem:ShowNotReady>
      </tem:GetTasks>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: You have to provide date in format that web-service expect. Which technology uses your server? Can you provide wsdl file? I see StartDate and EndDate are optionals. Does work the request without dates? You can try with date in format: 2008-10-26T21:32:52

Comment: Hi, thanks you for your reply. the wsdl file is locally because I need to test the web service. the program is build in c# and I was told that SOAPUI send an string but the program is expecting DateTime. The dates must to be inserted. Thanks

Comment: What's the error? What did the developers say about the correct date format when you asked them?

Comment: Try sending just the Year-Month-Day like YYYY-MM-DD format. You don't appear to be sending a string rather the date format you are using doesn't match what the service expects. Do what @SiKing has suggested.

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay. I was told that SOAPUI send an string with any format and the program is waiting for DateTime. there`s a way to convert in soapui before to send the request?

Answer (score 5):

Try the Sortable Date/Time Pattern, it works for me

```
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("S", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
```

IN XML

```
 <tem:StartDate>2014-01-10T15:51:24</tem:StartDate>
 <tem:EndDate>2018-01-10T15:51:24</tem:EndDate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a date in the format that web-service expect. 
i.e  2008-10-26