# Why do I get an error that there is an error in XML document?

Tags: c#, web-services, c#-4.0, soapui, asmx

I have a soap webservice hosted on localhost i.e. iis express using visual studio. I am sending it values using the SOAPUI. It works and debug if I am passing the correct values.

But If I pass an empty tag or value i.e. if a datetime is expected and I pass empty tag i.e.  then it throws error even before hitting the webservices method.

So is it a webservice error or a soapui error?

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <soap:Code>
            <soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value>
         </soap:Code>
         <soap:Reason>
            <soap:Text xml:lang="en">System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (41, 34). ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExactMultiple(String s, String[] formats, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
   at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String[] formats, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlCustomFormatter.ToDate(String value)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read3_Item(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read10_Item(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read11_DT_FunctionalLocation(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read12_SI_FunctionalLocation_In_Async()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()</soap:Text>
         </soap:Reason>
         <soap:Detail/>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Your soap needs a datetime parameter and you either did not provide it or it was in an incorrect format

Comment: Hi, if I pass it Datetime.Min from any test application or something like that it doesn't throw error. But in the SOAPUI it does like this. Do I need to handle it in code or is it a behavior?

Comment: It is like this and cannot be changed further since this is the wsdl that client has given us to make a webservice out of it.

Comment: My question is why does it even fail before going to the webservice

Comment: Chech how is written the datetime in SOAPUI, for example [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109802/soapui-dateformat-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't call it webservice or soapUI error: the service is working as expected and rejecting invalid content.

Within the WSDL that defines your webservice will be an XML Schema against which the webservice runtime environment can validate an incoming request. If the request fails this first line of defence, there's no point in invoking your service.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to "capture" the error when the request fails? Can that be done in IIS? What I'm looking to do is display a custom error message and even return a different status code